# CSS: Sliding an image with radio:checked (Pure CSS slider)

Tags: html, css

The goal is to create a slider using only CSS.
For this attempt I tried using a 200px by 1500px image that has '3 sections' (color coded)
Positioned absolutely with Left: 0, the default checked radio button shows the first 500px of the image (Slide 1), since the wrapper is 200x500 pixels with overflow hidden.
Checking the radio button via label for 'slide2' gives me the next 500px of the image (Slide 2) by positioning the image Left: -500px.
Which works fine for the time being.
The problem I've got is getting the image to slide -1000px, thus showing the final 500px of the image (Slide 3). It seems when I add a third radio input and label, the slider breaks and the other inputs don't do anything. In fact, the 1st radio button css sometimes seems pointless, since setting a transition on the image itself appears to be necessary to get the desired effect for the 'Slide 1' radio button.

Link to image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6yao.jpg

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css"/>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <input type="radio" id="slide1" name="radio" checked>
        <input type="radio" id="slide2" name="radio">
        <!--<input type="radio" id="slide3" name="radio">-->
        <img src="images/slides.jpg"/>
        <label for="slide1">slide1</label>
        <label for="slide2">slide2</label>
        <!--<label for="slide3">slide3</label>-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#wrap {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20;
    left: 0;
    transition: .5s ease-out;
    height: 200px;
    width: 1500px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

#slide1:checked + img {
    left: 0;
    transition: .5s ease-out;
}

#slide2:checked + img {
    left: -500px;
    transition: .5s ease-out;
}

/*#slide3:checked + img {
    left: -1500px;
    transition: .5s ease-out;
}*/
```

Appreciate the help! And if there's an easier/simpler way to do a slider with controls in just css, I'd love to know. Tried a couple of examples I've found online but none look or animate quite how I'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ya go - consolidated some of your CSS, extended it with a 3rd image, and am using `translateX()` and `opacity` to enhance the transition between slides.

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-out, transform .5s ease-out;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  /* transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-720deg); */ /* try this, it's nuts */
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input:checked + img {
  transform: translateX(0);
  /* transform: translateX(0) rotate(0); */ /* try this with the commented line above */
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

.controls {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

label {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: #fff;
  padding: .5em;
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <input type="radio" id="slide1" name="radio" checked>
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" />
  <input type="radio" id="slide2" name="radio">
  <img src="http://www.star2.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/happy-days-770x470.jpg">  
  <input type="radio" id="slide3" name="radio">
  <img src="https://timedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2016/08/henry-winkler.jpg?quality=85">
  <div class="controls">
    <label for="slide1">slide1</label>
    <label for="slide2">slide2</label>
    <label for="slide3">slide3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Michael that works great. Quick question: How would you go about setting a delay before the previous image slides back out? So it looks like the new image sliding in is overlapping it? Thank you very much!

Comment: @3412127 np. You can't do that with CSS alone. You'd need to use javascript. You're really limited in what you can do trying to build something like this with CSS.

Comment: @3412127 btw welcome to SO. Be sure to upvote posts if they help to encourage participation and show anyone who searches for your issue and finds this post which answers are good, and also be sure to accept an answer at some point (the checkmark by the answers)

Comment: @3412127 made a couple of edits. Altering the z-index of the active slide might make it look like the next slide is overlapping. Also added a couple of `rotate()` lines and commented them out, but you might check that out, too.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've tried the z-index but I don't think I'm seeing a difference but it's okay, I read your previous comment. The rotate is banana's! Looks tamer when slowed to 1 second duration though.

Comment: @3412127 if you slow the transition to 1s and remove the `opacity` change, maybe you can see the z-index. It basically just puts the next slide in front of the previous one every time you hit the button and change slides. If you're going forward (from 1 to 2, or 2 to 3) you won't see it since going forward the next slide will always be on top - but if you go backwards (from 3 to 2, or 2 to 1), without the z-index change, the next slide will slide in underneath the previous slide.