# Pure CSS Slider linked to radio buttons

Tags: css, radio-button, slider

I'm wondering if there's a way to create a clickable slider that's additionally controllable with radio buttons just by using native CSS - no JavaScript.

The slider should look like this
[image]

I thought of putting the images into the regarding radio buttons' labels, but positioning them relatively to the whole radio group container's wrapper and then add positive or negative margin to the images depending on what radio button is `:checked`.

This is what I got so far:

```css
.carousel__nav {
  display: flex;
}
.mwf-option label img {
  width: 182px;
  height: 95px;
}
.style-2 .mwf-option {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.style-2 .carousel__nav label.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}
.style-2 .mwf-option:nth-child(1) label.btn {
  left: calc(182px * 1);
}
.style-2 .mwf-option:nth-child(2) label.btn {
  left: calc(182px * 2);
}
.style-2 .mwf-option:nth-child(3) label.btn {
  left: calc(182px * 3);
}
.style-2 .mwf-option:nth-child(1) .mwf-radio:checked ~ label.btn {
  margin-left: 182px;
}
.style-2 .mwf-option:nth-child(3) .mwf-radio:checked ~ label.btn {
  margin-left: -182px;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel__wrapper style-2">
          <div class="carousel__nav">
            <span class="mwf-option">
              <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio-group" class="mwf-radio input-hidden">
              <label for="radio1" class="btn">
                <div class="VueCarousel-slide"><img id="slide-1" src="https://i.imgur.com/OhXJ7rk.jpg">
                </div>
              </label>
              <span class="btn">One</span>
            </span>
            <span class="mwf-option">
              <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio-group" class="mwf-radio input-hidden">
              <label for="radio2" class="btn">
                <div class="VueCarousel-slide"><img id="slide-2" src="https://i.imgur.com/6wxbv7n.jpg">
                </div>
              </label>
              <span class="btn">Two</span>
            </span>
            <span class="mwf-option">
              <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio-group" class="mwf-radio input-hidden" value="mwf7_2566_666">
              <label for="radio3" class="btn">
                <div class="VueCarousel-slide"><img id="slide-3" src="https://i.imgur.com/Cc0BzB8.jpg">
                </div>
              </label>
              <span class="btn">Three</span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I'm struggling since I'm not sure how to set margin to all of the images depending on the checked radio button. I'm currently using CSS's `~`-operator, but that only affects the following component, not all 3.

Additionally I want to add some `overflow: hidden` to the images wrapper, but since their first common wrapper is `.carousel__nav` I can't simply hide its overflow because that would also hide the radio buttons.

**I want to keep this HTML structure,** because it shall be possible to display the same component as a regular radio button group or as a slider by just changing a CSS class.

Is this possible by just using CSS, or do I definitely need some JavaScript here? I'd like to prevent it, but keeping the HTML structure has priority nr 1.

Comment: Hey, you can refer to this topic 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42405127/css-sliding-an-image-with-radiochecked-pure-css-slider , same case than yours ! Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, the main problem with only using CSS is it's quite rigid. Everything has to stated beforehand and if you change the number of slides you have to change a bunch of the CSS.

```css
:root {
  --total-slides: 3;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

[name=slider-group] {
  display: none;
}

.slider_container {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.slider {
  width: calc(var(--total-slides)*100vw);
  font-size: 0;
  transition: transform 600ms ease-in-out;
}

.slider_slide {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 140px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
  background: #f44336;
}

.slider_slide:nth-child(even) {
  background: #3F51B5;
}

#radio1:checked~.slider {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

#radio2:checked~.slider {
  transform: translateX(-100vw);
}

#radio3:checked~.slider {
  transform: translateX(-200vw);
}

.slider_nav {
  text-align: center;
  background: #37474F;
}

.slider_nav .btn {
  background-color: #607D8B;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider_container">
  <input type="radio" name="slider-group" id="radio1" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider-group" id="radio2" />
  <input type="radio" name="slider-group" id="radio3" />
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider_slide"></div>
    <div class="slider_slide"></div>
    <div class="slider_slide"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<nav class="slider_nav">
  <label class="btn" for="radio1">One</label>
  <label class="btn" for="radio2">Two</label>
  <label class="btn" for="radio3">Three</label>
</nav>
```